# Remove one value in hashmap instead of all values and key

Tags: java, hashmap

I have a hashmap which is `Map<String, Set<String>> tasks` . Inside the tasks I have some keys and keys have some values, not just a value.

I would like remove a value from hashmap with given key but I also want to keep other values there.

I mean like this `release = ["fix bug 1", "fix bugs 2" , "implement feature X"]` . now `release` is key(in String type) and has values(in Set type) `"fix bug 1", "fix bugs 2" , "implement feature X"` .. I would like to modified  `release` like this :

`release = ["implement feature X"]`

how can I remove 2 values??? Thanks

Comment: You'll need to get the `Set<String>`, and then remove from it like any other set.  The `Map` isn't really important to what you're doing.

Comment: but when I remove the value from ```Set<String>``` then i have to update hashMap, am I right ?? @LouisWasserman

Comment: I got ```ConcurrentModificationException``` exception

Comment: No.  You should not update the map.  If you're getting `ConcurrentModificationException`, then your code to remove the value from the set is wrong, probably because you're calling `set.remove(value)` in a loop instead of using `Iterator.remove()`, or using `removeIf` or `removeAll` not in a loop.

Answer (score 1):

Using the key you can get the Set you want and then remove the value:

```
map.get("key").removeIf(s -> s.equals("value"));
map.get("key").removeIf(s -> s.equals("value") || s.equals("value1"));
```

You can do more combinations.
There is not need to update the HashMap. it has the reference of Set and whatever happens to Set the HashMap knows it.

Comment: Of course, `removeIf(s -> s.equals("value"))` is the same as `remove("value")`.

Answer (score 0):

Your Map only contains *references* to Sets, so you can modify the Sets directly and the changes will be seen by the Map.

Which means you can do:

```
tasks.get("release").removeAll(Arrays.asList("fix bug 1", "fix bug 2"));
```

Or even:

```
tasks.get("release").retainAll(Arrays.asList("implement feature X"));
```